# Is the Rado graph the unique countable graph that has all finite graphs as induced subgraphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

I understand that since the Rado graph is the Fraïsse limit of the class of finite graphs, it is the unique *homogeneous* graph with this property. Is there another graph not isomorphic to the Rado graph that also has this property, but fails to be homogeneous?

I haven't found any clear statement that it is unique nor any such non-homogeneous example when searching around, but it feels like the answer to this should be well known...

Comment: I think there are many examples. The Rado graph plus an isolated point, or plus $n$ isolated points, the disjoint union of two Rado graphs, the disjoint union of all finite graphs . . .

Comment: Once again my intuition for infinity turns out to be infinitely flawed. (Or at least I have yet to find an upper bound for its flawedness.) Thank you.

Comment: I think that if (1) $G$ is connected and countable, and (2) for every finite graph $A$ and full subgraph $B$, any full embedding of $B$ in $G$ extends to a full embedding of $A$, then $G$ is isomorphic to the Rado graph.

Comment: @NeilStrickland You don’t need to assume connectedness. This characterization is more-or-less what “Fraïssé limit” means.

Comment: It doesn't even have to contain Rado's graph; just take a disjoint union of finite graphs, one of each isomorphism type.

Comment: bof's example generalises to any free amalgamation class. Given one, the disjoint union of all elements of the class is always universal, but it's only very rarely the Fraisse limit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the question is very well answered in comments (by multiple people), here’s a CW answer putting them all together.

**The Rado graph is not uniquely characterised, among countable graphs, by the property “every finite graph embeds”.**  It’s easy to give many counterexamples: the disjoint union of one copy of every finite graph; or (if you want connectedness) that disjoint union plus one extra vertex with an edge to every other; or the Rado graph union a point; or the disjoint union, or connected union, of two copies of the Rado graph…

However, **it is characterised by a natural strengthening of that property: “given any finite graph $H$ *and an embedding from some induced subgraph $H' \leq H$ into $G$*, there’s an embedding of $H$ *extending the given embedding of $H'$”.***  This is easily seen to be equivalent to the [extension property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rado_graph#Extension) as described in Wikipedia; similarly, it directly suffices for the back-and-forth argument sketched there, showing that any two countable graphs with this property are isomorphic.  It is the special case for graphs of one of the standard definitions/characterisations of the [Fraïssé limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_limit); in category-theoretic terms, it says the Rado graph is [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_object) with respect to finite extensions in the category of graphs and embeddings (or full homomorphisms).